# Managing Bookmarks the better way

Tags: browser, bookmarks

Somehow I am not a great fan of Browser Bookmarks, what would be an alternative solution to managing my Browsing links, sometimes I like only a section of the page and would like to tag them and keep it for offline viewing in the future.
What would be other effective ways to manage the internet(so to speak)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a local [tiddlywiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) and copy, paste and link in it

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com) for saving all the stuff you find interesting. Here's more info from the site:

> Stop forgetting stuff! With Evernote,
> remember everything and find it any
> time.
>
> - To-do lists
> - Snapshots Text and ink notes
> - Audio recordings
>
> Evernote can
> even recognize text in images. Take a
> snapshot of something and send it into
> Evernote. We'll make it searchable.

It also has Google Gerars integration, so you can use it offline if you want.

Comment: Is it open source / free software?

Comment: It's free (there are paid accounts as well which offer you a higher upload limit and support for more file types), but it's not opensource. It's a highly recommended service; I've heard a lot of praise for it and I like it as well. It's a bit overkill for me, though; I mostly use Google Tasks for note taking.

Comment: I want to like Evernote, but the lack of linux support, and gears only working in the desktop (not the mobile) version stop me.

Comment: You don't have to like it :). As I said, I prefer Google Tasks myself, but Evernote seemed better suited for what AeonFlux wanted.

Answer (score 2):

There's also ScrapBook for Firefox. From the add-on's page:

> ScrapBook is a Firefox extension,
>   which helps you to save Web pages and
>   easily manage collections. Key
>   features are lightness, speed,
>   accuracy and multi-language support.
>   Major features are:
>
> - Save Web page
> - Save snippet of Web page
> - Save Web site
> - Organize the collection in the same way as Bookmarks
> - Full text search and quick filtering search of the collection
> - Editing of the collected Web page
> - Text/HTML edit feature resembling Opera's Notes

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it sounds kludgy, but for me it works: if I encounter a link or piece of text I want to find in the future, I copy/paste it to Gmail and mail it to myself, adding a few selected keywords. Whenever I need to access the text/link, I search for one of the keywords. It's uncomplicated, doesn't require installing extensions or software and works from every computer.

Answer (score 1):

I use Google bookmarks and subscribe to the RSS feed of each tag as a bookmark folder. Saves messing about :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Bokemarks.com](http://www.bokemarks.com), which is an online bookmarks manager. It does not have the functionality you are asking for in regards to "saving a section of the webpage" but in regards to ways to "manage the internet" I like it a lot because it saves the "important" part of the webpage so it's easy to remember.